# Same running environment and codes but different output (one normal while any other environment sucks, web crawler with python 3.7.10)

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, web-crawler

I wrote a web crawler with python 3.7.10 and requests 2.26.0 to get some information from a website. The code is runnable in the original environment, but it didn't work in any other environment, even I made a new environment with the same version of python and requests, it only outputs unreadable things (garbled code), how could this happened?

the output of running codes under original environment is readable html texts, while the output of running the same codes in any other environment is something like this: [image]

I have compared their response, only the 'apparent_encoding' seems different and may influent the result, so i tried to set the same 'apparent_encoding' for it, but it didn't work. And I have also tried to decode text/content of the response with different code, but useless

I didn't change anything of the codes, how could this happened??? I'm very confused.

Here comes the brief version of the code:

```
import requests
url = r'https://www.example.com/filterData'
headers = {
            'Host': 'www.example.com',
            'Content-Length': str(49+len(kword)),
            'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="118", "Microsoft Edge";v="118", "Not=A?Brand";v="99"',
            'Content-Type': 'charset=UTF-8',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/118.0.2088.46',
            'sec-ch-ua-platform': "Windows",
            'Origin':'https://www.example.com',
            'Sec-Fetch-Site':'same-origin',
            'Sec-Fetch-Mode':'cors',
            'Sec-Fetch-Dest':'empty',
            'Referer':'https://www.example.com/search?cid=0&keys='+t_kword,
            'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Accept-Language':'zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6',
            
        }

DATA = {
            'pageid':queryParams[0],
            'keys':queryParams[1],
            'nid':queryParams[2],
            'cid':queryParams[3],
            'tag':queryParams[4],
            'status':queryParams[5]
        }
session = requests.Session()
response = session.post(url, headers=headers, data = DATA)
queryResult = response.text
```

the variable 'queryResult' is readable html text when I use original environment, while it output unreadable things under any other environment. I have tried Python 3.8.3/3.7.9/3.7.10/3.12.0 with requests of various versions, but useless. Can anybody tell me what happened?